# get the 32 high bits of multiplying two unsigned integers (HW)

Tags: c, bit

I am reading CSAPP and trying to complete the homework questions. Assume w = 32, 2.75 is about getting the high 32 bits from multiplying two 32 bits unsigned integers. Given the function `int signed_high_prod(int x, int y)` which computes the high-order 32 bits of x . y for the case where x and y are in two’s- complement form. `int signed_high_prod(int x, int y)` should be used in implementing `unsigned int unsigned_high_prod(unsigned x, unsigned y)`.

By googling I found `x'.y' = x.y + x.y_31.2^32 + y.x_31.2^32 + x_31.y_31.2^64`, where x' and y' are unsigned form of x and y respectively.

I still can not understand the answer.

```
unsigned unsigned_high_prod(unsigned x, unsigned y){
    unsigned p = (unsigned) signed_high_prod((int) x, (int) y)
    if((int) x < 0){
        p += y;
    }
    if((int) y < 0){
        p += x;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Why the final term has no effect of the result ? why when `x < 0` so `x_31 = 1`, plus `y` ? and the same with `y`.

Answer (score 3):

To convert a signed, 2's complement, 32-bit integer to an unsigned 32-bit integer, we add 2³² to its value if it is negative.

`signed_high_prod` does a signed multiplication and returns bits 63 to 32 of the product. We want `unsigned_high_prod` to do the same for unsigned multiplication and to make use of `signed_high_prod` and then compensate for the difference between unsigned and signed multiplication.

```
Let N(i) = { 1, i < 0
           { 0, i >= 0

Let U(i) = i + N(i)·2³² { −2³¹ <= i < 2³¹ }
```

Then:

```
U(x)·U(y) = (x + N(x)·2³²)·(y + N(y)·2³²)
          = x·y + x·N(y)·2³² + N(x)·2³²·y + N(x)·2³²·N(y)·2³²
          = x·y + x·N(y)·2³² + y·N(x)·2³² + N(x)·N(y)·2⁶⁴

⌊U(x)·U(y)/2³²⌋ = ⌊x·y/2³²⌋ + x·N(y) + y·N(x) + N(x)·N(y)·2³²
```

Since the arithmetic on unsigned, 32-bit integers will be performed modulo 2³², we have:

```
⌊U(x)·U(y)/2³²⌋ mod 2³²  = (⌊x·y/2³²⌋ + x·N(y) + y·N(x) + N(x)·N(y)·2³²) mod 2³²
                         = (⌊x·y/2³²⌋ + x·N(y) + y·N(x)) mod 2³²
```

I believe that accounts for the calculations performed by your `unsigned_high_prod` function.

Comment: If modulo 2³² is performed, will some bits get lost ?

Comment: @user2018791 Not in this case. The result of the multiplication fits in 64 bits. The division by 2³², rounded towards minus infinity ('floor') gives us the top 32 bits. The mod 2³² on the 32-bit, unsigned number has no effect on it.

Comment: @user2018791 The mod 2³² step at the end was mainly to show that the `unsigned_high_prod` function doesn't need to take account of the term involving N(x)·N(y)·2³² since it is a multiple of 2³² and so equals 0 mod 2³². Note that (A mod N) + (B mod N) is the same as (A + B) mod N, so the mod 2³² could have been done on each term individually and it wouldn't have made any difference. I.e. `(⌊x·y/2³²⌋ + x·N(y) + y·N(x) + N(x)·N(y)·2³²) mod 2³²` equals `⌊x·y/2³²⌋ mod 2³² + x·N(y) mod 2³² + y·N(x) mod 2³² + N(x)·N(y)·2³² mod 2³²`.

Answer (score 2):

To perform bit-level multiplication we have to first extend the bits then  go through a series of shifts and additions. For example, assuming w = 3, let `x = [011]` and `y = [101]`. (i.e. `x = 3` and `y = -3 (signed) or 5 (unsigned)`)

To perform the unsigned product, we first zero-extend as follows:          (ignoring bits 6 and above)

```
     000 011
   * 000 101
    --------
     000 011
   + 001 100
    --------
     001 111
    ========
```

Therefore, the unsigned high order bits are `[001]`

To perform the signed product, we first sign-extend as follows:

```
     000 011
   * 111 101
    --------
     000 011
   + 001 100
   + 011 000  **
   + 110 000  **
   + 100 000  **
    --------
     110 111
    ========
```

Therefore, the signed high order bits are `[110]`

Note, the difference between the signed and unsigned high order bits (as indicated by ** above) is that we have added `[111] * [011]` in the signed case. Therefore, we have to subtract this amount to get the unsigned high order bits.

```
The unsigned high order bits = [110] - [111] * [011]
                             = [110] - [101]
                             = [110] + [011] ??
                             = [001] (as above)
```

Because `[111] = -1`, the correction amount, `- [111] * [011]` is equivalent to `- (-1 * x) = x`.

Therefore, when `y` is negative (as in this case), we have to correct the result by adding `x`.  Simlarly, when `x` is negative, we have to correct the result by adding `y`.

`?? -[101] = ~[101] + 1 = [010] + [001] = [011]`

Comment: This example to explain the code in the question and illustrate @Ian Abbot 's nice proof.

Answer (score 1):

- x'.y' = x.y + x.y_31.2^32 + y.x_31.2^32 + x_31.y_31.2^64

Here are the prerequisites you are supposed to know

1. x' and y' are unsigned  and x,y are signed
2. to get the low-order 32 bits of x*y by using  "mod 2^32"
3. to get the high-order 32 bits of x*y by using    "/ 2^32"

Let's begin

To get the high-order 32 bits of x'*y', we use "/ 2^32"

```
x'.y' /  2^32=unsigned_high_prod(unsigned x,unsigned y)
=(x.y + x.y_31.2^32 + y.x_31.2^32 + x_31.y_31.2^64)/2^32
=x.y/2^32 + x.y_31 + y.x_31 + x_31.y_31.2^32
=signed_high_prod(int x, int y) + x.y_31 + y.x_31 + x_31.y_31.2^32
```

But what we got  are  not limited  in  32  bits,  apparently  the  result y.x_31 + x_31.y_31.2^32  has  overflowed,  what we  are  supposed to get is just a 32 bits  number.  So  we use mod  2^32  to get the right answer.

(signed_high_prod(int x, int y) + x.y_31 + y.x_31 + x_31.y_31.2^32) mod 2^32
= signed_high_prod(int x, int y) + x.y_31 + y.x_31

It  ends with  :

**unsigned_high_prod(unsigned x,unsigned y)=
    Signed_high_prod(int x, int y) + x.y_31 + y.x_31**

So  it is  obvious  that the  code was right.

Because if int x < 0, it means the x_31 == 1, so you have to add y.

Otherwise  x_31 == 0,  you do not bother to do anything  since   y.x_31 == 0

the same with the y